# Как унаследовать свойства главного класса в дочернем при динамической инициализации?

Tags: php, ооп, наследование, рефлексия, миграция

Есть два класса: `Migration` и `m20190730_081143_test`. Второй же наследуется от `Migration` и имеет два метода `up` и `down`.

В классе `Migration` я получаю список всех файлов миграции (второй класс) из папки и хочу вызвать у них метод `up`. В основном классе в `__construct` я инициализирую `$this->db = new Database();` и другую небольшую логику.

Проблема заключается в том, что когда я вызываю метод `up` у дочерних классов, то у них параметры `$db` не совпадает.

```php
foreach ($this->getNewMigrations() as $newMigration) {
            require_once $newMigration['path'];

            $migrationClass = new $newMigration['name']();
            $this->db->beginTransaction();
            $migrationClass->up();
            $this->db->commit();
        }
```

Этот код находится в главном классе и инициализирует транзакцию `$db->isTransaction`. Если в методе `up` дочернего класса сделать вывод `$db`, то `$db->isTransaction` будет `false`, хотя в главном классе `true`.

Как мне стыковать их и сделать так, чтобы `$db` был у всех одинаковый (общий)?

P.S. Мне надо, чтобы свойства головного класса были основными, а дочерние классы пользовались ими (не инициализировали их самостоятельно) даже после их изменения в главном классе. Менять содержимое дочерних классов нельзя (только методы `up` и `down`)

Привожу классы:

**Migration**

```php
class Migration
{
    /**
     * @var Database
     */
    public $db;

    private $settings;

    public function __construct ()
    {
         $this->db = new Database();
    }

    public function __desctruct()
    {
        $this->db->closeConnection();
        $this->db = null;
    }

    public function actionUp()
    {
        foreach ($this->getNewMigrations() as $newMigration) {
            require_once $newMigration['path'];

            $migrationClass = new $newMigration['name']();
            // Вот тут как раз я изменяю состояние свойства $db у родителя
            // А оно, как я выяснил (измененное) не отражается у наследников
            $this->db->beginTransaction();
            $migrationClass->up();
            $this->db->commit();
        }
    }

    public function actionDown()
    {

    }
```

**Сама миграция**

```php
class m20190730_081143_test extends Core\Migrations\Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        var_dump($this->db);
    }

    public function down()
    {

    }
}
```

**Контроллер для консоли**

```php
use Core\Migrations\Migration;

require_once 'index.php';
require_once 'fw/Core/Migrations/Migration.php';

$action = 'action' . $argv[1];
$params = array_key_exists(2, $argv) ? $argv[2] : null;
$migrationClass = new Migration();

if (!method_exists($migrationClass, $action)) {
    exit (Console::writeError("Unidentified command '{$argv[1]}'"));
}

$migrationClass->$action($params);
```

Comment: Вопрос даже больше заключается в том, если я изменю свойство родительского класса, то как мне отразить его и в дочернем.

Comment: Было бы гуд посмотреть на классы, так не совсем понятно чё за чё.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin , внес части классов по вопросу. Можно кстати метод `beginTransaction` вызывать у наследников. Просто интересно как сделать синхронизацию изменений свойств главного класса и наследников.

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе не приведен полный код классов, но с вероятностью 95% предполагаю, что в классе m20190730_081143_test Вы переопределили свойство $db, написав что-то вроде

```
public|protected|private $db;
```

Это переопределенное свойство перекрыло существовавшее (и инициализированное) в родительском классе. Оставшиеся 5% за то, что где-то Вы это свойство, определенное в родительском классе, изменяете в каком-либо методе дочернего класса.

> Как мне стыковать их и сделать так, чтобы $db был у всех одинаковый (общий)?

В конструкторе унаследованных классов воспользуйтесь вызовом конструктора родительского класса, затем добавьте недостающую логику и инициализацию.

```php
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    // дополнительная инициализация
}
```

Убедитесь, что все свойства родительского класса, которые должны быть доступны в дочерних классах, имеют область видимости protected и не переопределяются в дочерних классах.

> Мне надо, чтобы свойства головного класса были основными, а дочерние классы пользовались ими (не инициализировали их самостоятельно) даже после их изменения в главном классе. Менять содержимое дочерних классов нельзя (только методы up и down)

В дочерних классах уберите все переопределения свойств родительского класса. В идеале - сделайте свойства родительского классе private и предоставьте доступ к ним с помощью методов getXxx(). Область видимости для гетеров сделайте такой же, как должна быть у свойства. Т.е. для private/protected свойств сделайте гетеры final protected, для public-свойств - соответственно final public. Так Вы обезопасите себя от какого-либо способа использования свойств родительского класса напрямую. Методы родительского класса, которые нельзя менять в дочерних классах, определите как final - так Вы застрахуетесь от их переопределения в дочерних классах.

P.S. Такие вопросы необходимо задавать прилагая полный листинг кода. Иначе приходится "гадать по IP".

P.P.S. Кроме наследования существует еще и композиция. Подумайте. Возможно, для Вас безопаснее (в плане использования) будет воспользоваться именно ей.

```
class m20190730_081143_test
{
    protected $migration;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->migration = new Migration();
        // инициализация объекта Migration
    }

    public function up() {
        // 
    }

    public function down() {
        // 
    }
}
```

Comment: Если Вы считаете, что меняете, что меняете что-то у родителя, именно тут - **$migrationClass = new $newMigration['name']();**, то должен Вас разочаровать. Это не так. В контроллере Вы создали экземпляр класса Migration. В методе actionUp() Вы создали экземпляр класса m20190730_081143_test. Но это -  **другой экземпляр**. В каждом из экземпляров класса Migration Вы создаете собственное **новое** соединение с базой данных: **$this->db = new Database();**. Транзакцию запускаете в одном соединении, а SQL-код выполняете в другом.

Comment: Рекомендую воспользоваться паттерном "Одиночка" для класса Database и пользовать одно соединение с базой. Тогда будет работать.

Comment: Ну или действительно, как Вы и написали в вопросе, запускать beginTransaction у **экземпляра дочернего класса** $migrationClass. А то получается так, будто Вы взяли 2 молотка, в один забили клинышек, чтобы с ручки не слетал, а другим машете - и удивляетесь, что железяка с ручки сползает. :)